# LinkageError with deployment of play framework 1.2.5 application

Tags: playframework-1.x

Play framework 1.2.5 was already setup on an ubuntu 11 server.  I stopped the process, ran play clean and then deployed the new app (I have since then ran play clean a few times as well without any luck).   I keep getting LinkageErrors and the application is throwing classcast exceptions for objects for different classes.  Any suggestions to help pinpoint what's causing the issue and how best to resolve it - thanks in advance.

```
Oops: LinkageError
An unexpected error occured caused by exception LinkageError: loader (instance of  play/classloading/ApplicationClassloader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "models/testModel/TestClass"
```

Reference to play framework is still set up in the system path.  I am using "play start" to run the application.

Comment: I will try play run and see if the behavior is somehow different.

Comment: I did not observe any difference with the run command.  I can run the same package on my local computer and another server.  The environments appear to be identical (same OS version, JDK version etc.)

Comment: I did not try cleaning anything in the framework directory - looking at replacing the play directory to see if that fixes it.  Will look into the framework directory later to see if I could have changed anything there to fix this issue.

Comment: even replacing the play directory and rebooting the server has not fixed the issue - I do not see the same issue on two other servers (and I now get new Linkage errors as opposed to the previous ones)

Comment: I switched mode to prod (this is still a test server so I wanted to use Dev) - I was able to get more verbose error messages this time around with prod mode (it was complaining about templates which were not even being used but were not cleaned from the templates directory - not sure if this was also happening for Dev since the same deployment worked on another server).  The app is working fine in prod mode and its running locally and another test server in Dev mode without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Prod mode in application.conf and check if you receive more verbose error messages during pre-compilation.  Also, replacing your deployment or even the play directory might help (though that did not resolve the issue in my case).  Hope it helps.